# Haskell mutable vector in record

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a record that contains a mutable vector and then print the record.

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as VM

data Foo s = Foo {bar :: VM.STVector s Int}
```

I have a function that creates an instance ok,

```
mkFoo :: PrimMonad m => m (Foo (PrimState m))
mkFoo = do
  b <- VM.generate 5 (const 3)
  return Foo {bar = b}
```

When I try to create a function that prints the record, though, it's giving errors.

```
printFoo :: PrimMonad m => m (Foo (PrimState m)) -> IO ()
printFoo f = do
  let b = bar f
  printf "%d\n" (VM.read b 0)
```

It's giving the error,

```
 * Couldn't match type `m' with `Foo'
      `m' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          printFoo :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                      PrimMonad m =>
                      m (Foo (PrimState m)) -> IO ()
```

What's the trick to being able to get at the mutable data?

Comment: The mistakes you're making here are very common Haskell newbie mistakes. Learning Haskell with mutable things is like learning juggling with knives or chainsaws, or learning C with `goto` or `setjmp`/`longjmp`.

Comment: But anyway, here's a few hints: (1) Keep in mind the difference between `let x = y` and `x <- y`. (2) Have a look at some of the functions in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.7.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Primitive.html (3) When you write a polymorphic function, the caller gets to pick what the type variables are, and the implementation has to be able to deal with any possible choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend sticking to `IO` at this point and look at `ST` and `PrimMonad` later as they are more complicated. For your program that would look like this:

```hs
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as VM
import Text.Printf

data Foo = Foo { bar :: VM.IOVector Int }

mkFoo :: IO Foo
mkFoo = do
  b <- VM.generate 5 (const 3)
  return Foo {bar = b}

printFoo :: IO Foo -> IO ()
printFoo f = do
  let b = bar f
  printf "%d\n" (VM.read b 0)
```

Now the first error you get is:

```
M.hs:13:15: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Foo’ with actual type ‘IO Foo’
    • In the first argument of ‘bar’, namely ‘f’
      In the expression: bar f
      In an equation for ‘b’: b = bar f
   |
13 |   let b = bar f
   |               ^
```

This message tells you that the function `bar` expects a value of type `Foo` as input, but you give it a value of type `IO Foo`. There are multiple ways to fix this. Since this function runs in `IO` we can first unwrap the argument like this:

```
printFoo :: IO Foo -> IO ()
printFoo f = do
  f' <- f
  let b = bar f'
  printf "%d\n" (VM.read b 0)
```

However, I would say this is not very idiomatic. Instead it is more useful to require that the input to your function is already unwrapped, like this:

```
printFoo :: Foo -> IO ()
printFoo f = do
  let b = bar f
  printf "%d\n" (VM.read b 0)
```

Now you will still get another error message (GHC versions before 9.0.1 will show a less readable error):

```
/tmp/M.hs:9:26: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0’
                     with ‘GHC.Prim.RealWorld’
      Expected: VM.MVector (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0) Int
        Actual: VM.IOVector Int
      The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
    • In the first argument of ‘VM.read’, namely ‘b’
      In the second argument of ‘printf’, namely ‘(VM.read b 0)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: printf "%d\n" (VM.read b 0)
  |
9 |   printf "%d\n" (VM.read b 0)
  |                          ^
```

This error is vague, because the `VM.read` function can be used in many different ways and it is not clear which way you intend. If you write the explicit type signature `VM.read :: VM.IOVector a -> Int -> IO a`,like this:

```
printFoo :: Foo -> IO ()
printFoo f = do
  let b = bar f
  printf "%d\n" ((VM.read :: VM.IOVector a -> Int -> IO a) b 0)
```

(You could also use the `TypeApplications` extension and write `VM.read @IO b 0`)

Then the error message becomes clearer:

```
M.hs:14:3: error:
    • No instance for (PrintfArg (IO Int))
        arising from a use of ‘printf’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        printf "%d\n" ((VM.read :: VM.IOVector a -> Int -> IO a) b 0)
      In the expression:
        do let b = bar f
           printf "%d\n" ((VM.read :: VM.IOVector a -> Int -> IO a) b 0)
      In an equation for ‘printFoo’:
          printFoo f
            = do let b = ...
                 printf "%d\n" ((VM.read :: VM.IOVector a -> Int -> IO a) b 0)
   |
14 |   printf "%d\n" ((VM.read :: VM.IOVector a -> Int -> IO a) b 0)
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This tells you that you cannot use a value of type `IO Int` as an argument to the `printf` function. In this case the fix is simply to unwrap the value before printing it:

```
printFoo :: Foo -> IO ()
printFoo f = do
  let b = bar f
  x <- VM.read b 0
  printf "%d\n" x
```

Now the file compiles without errors, but how do you actually use these functions? If you naively try to call `printFoo mkFoo` then you will again get an error about not being able to match the expected type `Foo` with the actual type `IO Foo`. Again the solution is to unwrap, in GHCi you can do that like this:

```
ghci> f <- mkFoo
ghci> printFoo f
3
```

If you want to use this in another function then you can do that similarly, for example in the main function:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  f <- mkFoo
  printFoo f
```

Comment: How would you do it with ST and Prim? My biggest issue with Haskell right now is how bad immutable data structures can perform, so I'd like to figure out how to use mutable data to have that option. Being forever tied to IO seems less than desirable.

Comment: The key thing you need to know is that with the ST monad, you can't do anything in IO and you have to end up with immutable data before you do anything else.  You can have state modified within the ST part of your program, but it has to be tightly locked up; none of that state can possibly escape.  That's probably too complex to explain in a StackOverflow answer; look for tutorials and documentation on ST.  That said, immutable data structures can perform a lot better than you'd think.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'll look at restructuring things to keep them separate. I'm well aware of the performance characteristics of immutable data. For most things, especially I/O tasks, it's fine. For CPU heavy tasks on large data, going from O(1) to O(logn) means taking several minutes instead of a couple seconds.

Comment: Uh, what? For log n to be a factor of 60 slower, your data has to be of size 2^60, or 10^18.